# Intel XDK (Applications in HTML5)

Tags: android, html, intel-xdk

Well, I have an application in HTML5, Intel made ​​the XDK (build in android)

Well when I install and then open the application, when al tightness input, it opens the keyboard and locks the application, making it close. Can you help me?

Comment: need more info, can u post the code on jsbin or somewhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a code sample or more information it is hard to help you but I will suggest you try one of the demos that has an input field on an Android device and see if you have better results. Then at least you can look at the sample code to try to debug your application.

- Open the Intel XDK
- Click Start a New Project
- Click Work with a Demo
- Click on the first sample 'App Framework'
- Click Use this Demo
- Name your project
- Click CREATE

You can use the Develop>>Design view to play with the input field or the Emulate tab to test the input field.

- Click on the BUILD tab
- Under Android click BUILD
- Click UPLOAD TO SERVER
- Click BUILD APP NOW
- Click DOWNLOAD apk
- Open a console or terminal prompt
- Use adb install *.apk to install your app on device

Use the input field.

To debug your application:

- Click Emulate tab
- Click on the little bug in the top left corner of the Intel XDK tool bar next to the reload button.
- Click Console in the pop-up dialog
- See if there are any errors in your application in red font.

We have a webinar on debugging that will be posted soon but for now you can reference this video for an overview on how to debug an app remotely on your device: 
https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/videos/how-to-debug-apps-remotely-using-the-intel-xdk

You can add several console.log("gets here! line #: 27"); in your code and you will see them in the console window when you run your application remotely or in the emulate tab.